How can I work with FastAPI websocket endpoint and rabbitmq streams (basic_consume)
I am trying to stream data from my device to a rabbitmq server and then consume it on my backend and websocket it to the front-end. This is my code:
@router.websocket("/ws/messages")
async def websocket_messages(
    websocket: WebSocket,
    device_name: str,
    pipeline_name: str,
    username: str = Depends(get_current_user_ws)
):
    await websocket.accept()
    pipeline = await websocket.receive_text()
    queue_name = pipeline_name
    result = channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, arguments={
        "x-queue-type": "stream", "x-max-length-bytes": 20_000_000_000}, durable=True)
    queue = result.method.queue
    channel.queue_bind(exchange=STREAMING_EXCHANGE, queue=queue,
                       routing_key=f"{device_name}/{pipeline_name}")
    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)

    pipeline_visualizer = PipelineVisualizer(json.loads(pipeline))

    async def on_message(channel, method, props, body):
        if body is None:
            # No message received, adjust sleep if needed
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        payload_str = body.decode("utf-8")
        record_data = json.loads(payload_str)
        # Draw pipeline results
        data, data_type = pipeline_visualizer.render_frame(
            record_data)

        output = {"messages": record_data}

        if data_type == "image":
            _, image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', data)
            image = image.tobytes()
            image = base64.b64encode(image).decode('ascii')
            output.update({
                "visualizationData": image,
                "type": "image"
            })
        elif data_type == "pointcloud":
            with open("./out.pcd", "rb") as fp:
                data_bytes = fp.read()
            pointcloud = base64.b64encode(data_bytes).decode('ascii')
            output.update({
                "visualizationData": pointcloud,
                "type": "pointcloud"
            })

        await websocket.send_text(json.dumps(output))
        await asyncio.sleep(1/60)
        channel.stop_consuming()

    try:
        channel.basic_consume(
            queue=queue, auto_ack=False, on_message_callback=on_message)
        channel.start_consuming()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        await websocket.close()

I have tried using threads and it didn't work. This code was working just fine when I was using basic_get with the default queue. But as it turns out we need more throughput performance for the data streaming. Reading the rabbitmq docs, they say stream queue's are the way to go when you need more performance. And that is where I am.

so what is the problem? What means didn't work.? If you get error message then show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image). We can't run it, we can't see your computer and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question.

It will basically block the endpoint. It doesn't show an error message, but if you try to stop the requests from the front-end, it will not let you, because the "start_consuming" loop is blocking the communication.
